# Rigidbody addForce on moving and standing player is different

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my player dash at where he's looking. The code below works but it gives 2 different result.

1. If the player dash and move at the same time, the player gets pushed a few units.
2. If the player dash only, the player gets pushed 4/5 times the one above.

How do I get result 1 for both of them whether they are moving or standing still.

```
private void Start() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void Update()
{
    horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    direction = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0f, verticalInput).normalized;

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
        isDashing = true;
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate() {
    Move();

    if(isDashing){
        Dash();
    }
}

void Move()
{
    if(direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
    {
        float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + camera.eulerAngles.y;
        float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity, 0.1f);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);

        Vector3 moveDirection = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
        moveDirection.y = rb.velocity.y;
        rb.velocity = moveDirection * currentSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

void Dash()
{
    rb.AddForce(transform.forward * dashForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    isDashing = false;
}
```